# Knapsack: there is a polynomial solution in bit terms?

Tags: time-complexity, np-complete, knapsack-problems

I'm reading about Knapsack problem. The approaches to solve that I found:

- Branch and bound
- Brute force
- Dynamic programming
- Memory functions
- Greedy

All solutions have exponential time in terms of bits. There is a solution (maybe an approximation algorithm) that solve Knapsack problem with polynomial time in bit terms?

Comment: No, but you can always invent one, which will prove $P = NP$, so good luck.

Comment: @EvilJS No one approximation? Heuristic?

Comment: [LMGTFY](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15854-f05/www/scribe/lec10.pdf), yes there is FPTAS approximation

Comment: We want you to do a significant amount of research before asking, to see if you can find the answer in standard resources; see, e.g., http://cs.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask.  There's little point in us repeating material that's already well described in standard resources.  In this case, your question is answered on Wikipedia -- if the answer can be found in the obvious place in Wikipedia (or in any reasonable textbook), you probably haven't done enough research before asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is answered in the Wikipedia article on the knapsack problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Computational_complexity, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Approximation_algorithms.